# Samba (client) on 22.10 permissions issue on saving from apps

Tags: networking, permissions, mount, samba

I've successful installed an Open Media Vault NAS and make some shares.
All works fine, I can create new folder, new blank files, copy files and folder from and to the shares but when I try to save from some applications (*ie save a tar directly inside the share with Engrampa*) get a **"isufficent permission"**. Same think trying to flash a pendrive using etcher and a .img stored inside the shares or save *some kind* of documents.

The weird I can save any kind of text file but cant open or save openoffice/office docs...
Can't save audio file but imgs have no issues...

Using the same shares in MacOs or Win all works fine.

I'm using smb with **no persistent** mounting (*etc/fstab*) but accessing it from "network" in caja.

**PS** where the hell it mount the shares?

Tnks for the help.

Comment: you mount the share in fstab

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper way to mount NAS shares w/o password in fstab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130762/proper-way-to-mount-nas-shares-w-o-password-in-fstab)